# How to allow on postfix/iredmail to set arbitrary from header?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, iredmail

I've set up mail server with iRedMail. It should act as an SMTP server for web app. Postfix is restricted only for localhost usage.

Let's assume that I create an account `web@example.com`.

What I need is to allow set arbitrary `from` header, e.g. `bar@example.com`, or even `baz@my-second-domain.com`

Currently this is rejecting:

```
postfix/smtpd[7386]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ***[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.0 <notlviv@pb.org.ua>: Sender address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<notlviv@pb.org.ua> to=<some@email.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.0.1]>
```

How can this be allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out:

```
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes # set to no
# Sender restrictions
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    reject_unlisted_sender # comment this
```